# textmate how to insert new line above current line?

Tags: textmate

is there a keyboard shortcut for inserting a new line above the current line? Kind of the opposite of cmd+return

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I just found out that optional+cmd+return should be able to do it. And indeed, I can achieve what I wanted in every file extension except for files that end in .js.coffee, in which case, it inserts a ";" and adds a new line below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, that macro is part of the Source bundle and is only active within the following scopes:

```
source.ruby | source.ocaml | source.fsharp | source.python | source.haskell | text.html
```

Not sure why that is since it's widely applicable to many different bundles.  Of course you can always open the bundle editor (Ctrl-Opt-Command b), go to the Source bundle, find the macro called "**Move to BOL and Insert LF**" and remove the scope selector or change it to something like:

```
source | text
```

If you also want it to do the same thing in .coffee.js files, you can/should delete the macro in whatever bundle is active for those files (CoffeeScript?)

Comment: Hey Jay, I went with your first approach, I added "| source.coffee" and it now works!!Thanks!